# compiling Win64 bit library using MingW64 compiled libCurl

Tags: windows, cygwin, mingw, libcurl, mingw-w64

I need 64 bit windows library for my 64 bit library. I am not able to find any 64 bit libcurl from the libcurl community. They only provide 64 bit in MingW64 or CygWin.

My problem is I dont if I can use 64 bit libCurl compiled in MingW or CygWin in windows or not? if it can be used, how can I do it?

Is there a way I can compile my own 64 bit Windows version? Or Has any one in past tried it?

I am referring:- http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

Answer (score 2):

I am having this issue too, but I did seem to get the x64 libcurl.  I downloaded the 64bit curl and from extracting it and looking through the curl files found the libcurl.  Looking at the documentation in curl-7.43.0 => winbuild => build.windows helped me set the "target architecture" to x64.  Then somewhere in the curl directory is the libcurl.lib they use and you can just copy paste that.

Note:

Libcurl wasn't compiling correctly for me.  Updating the Windows SDK fixed this on my Virtual Machine.

Comment: I also found that compiling libCurl lilb in 64 bit version about 8 months ago... definitely by reading the docs and doing some hit and trial. cannot remember now. Thanks for your answer!